# Rails won't install on Ubuntu because of builder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gem

Can someone explain why gem thinks I don't have builder >= 2.1.2 even though I clearly have 3.0.0?

```
jason@ve:~$ gem install rails --pre
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
        activemodel requires builder (~> 2.1.2, runtime)
jason@ve:~$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

abstract (1.0.0)
activesupport (3.0.3, 3.0.0.rc2)
builder (3.0.0)
erubis (2.6.6)
i18n (0.5.0)
mail (2.2.13)
memcache-client (1.8.5)
mime-types (1.16)
polyglot (0.3.1)
rack (1.2.1)
rack-mount (0.6.13)
rack-test (0.5.6)
text-format (1.0.0)
text-hyphen (1.0.0)
treetop (1.4.9)
tzinfo (0.3.23)
jason@ve:~$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `~> 2.1.2` designation means "greater than or equal to version 2.1.2, but not including the next major version. With a three-component version like 2.1.2, this means builder 2.1.2, 2.1.3, 2.1.4, etc. are all valid but 2.2.0 or 3.0.0 would be invalid.